# discord.py and private messages

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make discord-bot on phyton. Although I have understood discord API, I can't get the robot to send messages to members of server in private mail. Could you help me please

```
if message.content.startswith(myname + '!btcprice'):
    print('[command]: btcprice ')
    btc_price_usd, btc_price_rub = get_btc_price()
    msg = 'USD: ' + str(btc_price_usd) + ' | RUB: ' + str(btc_price_rub)
    await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Comment: `send_message` accepts `member` objects when called, which will then send a PM to that member. Please provide a code example of you want further assistance

Comment: @Benjin I provided a code example, How can I send message from 5 line as the private message to the user but not to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are calling this from the `on_message` event, in which case to send a PM you can get the `member` object from `message.author`. You can PM the user with this.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith(myname + '!btcprice'):
        print('[command]: btcprice ')
        btc_price_usd, btc_price_rub = get_btc_price()
        msg = 'USD: ' + str(btc_price_usd) + ' | RUB: ' + str(btc_price_rub)
        await client.send_message(message.author, msg)
```